# Mongoose: generate empty json from model

Tags: json, node.js, express, mongoose

I have such schema in my mongoose `category` model.

```
var categorySchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    order: Number
});
```

How can I generate empty json with these params to use it in my textarea when I want to add new category? This is example what do I want to get:

```
{
    "title": "",
    "description": "",
    "order": 
}
```

So I will simply fill these fields and then make POST request to my API and insert category data to database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a static method for the category schema that will output a data object to send back to the client to fill out your textarea. Something like:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  description: String,
  order: Number
});

categorySchema.statics.getSkeleton = function () {
  var data = {};
  Object.keys(categorySchema.paths).forEach(function (path) {
    return path !== '_id' ? data[path] = "" : false;
  });
  return data;
}
```

And then you can consume it thusly:

```
var textAreaDefaults = Category.getSkeleton();
```